# Error: Cannot find module './_freeGlobal'

Tags: node.js

> Error: Cannot find module './_freeGlobal'
>       at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)

When I try to delete this module, there is a message that I cannot find another module. Almost all modules are not found

Comment: Before deleting please check modules are installed or not, To check run this command `npm list express`, This command will show you express module is available or not.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this same issue in a React app. I simply ran `npm install` in my project folder and that fixed the problem.